# How can I authenticate a user that does not belong to Domain Users in dotnetcore?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

For security and management reasons, we are creating user entries in a separate container, adding them to a separate group, making that group primary, and then removing them from the Domain Users group.  I have these steps all working, but now I can't find a way to authenticate them.  I don't know if it's the classes I'm using or my arguments, or what.

Assuming:

```
AD_server = fully.qualified.domain
container = OU=My Users,OU=Accounts,DC=fully,DC=qualified,DC=domain
group = CN=App Users,OU=Software,DC=fully,DC=qualified,DC=domain
user = CN=Example,OU=Software,DC=fully,DC=qualified,DC=domain
sAMAccountName = Example
userPrincipalName = Example@MyUsers.fully.qualified.domain
```

I've tried

```
new LdapConnection(
  new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(AD_server)
).Bind(
  new NetworkCredential(userPrincipalName,password)
)

new LdapConnection(
  new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(AD_server)
).Bind(
  new NetworkCredential(sAMAccountName,password)
)

new DirectoryEntry(
  "LDAP://"+AD_server+"/"+container,
  sAMAccountName,
  password
)

new DirectoryEntry(
  "LDAP://"+AD_server+"/"+container,
  userPrincipalName ,
  password
)

new DirectoryEntry(
  "LDAP://"+AD_server+"/"+group,
  sAMAccountName,
  password
)

new DirectoryEntry(
  "LDAP://"+AD_server+"/"+group,
  userPrincipalName ,
  password
)

new DirectoryEntry(
  "LDAP://"+AD_server+"/"+group,
  user,
  password
)
```

I've also tried using the PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials() method without success.

During creation:

```
this.principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
  AD_server, // serves as domain and AD server
  container,
  adminUser,
  adminPassword);
```

The admin credentials have permissions to make changes to the domain.
To create a user (starts with a transfer object):

```
UserPrincipal userPrincipal =
    UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, user.UserId + upnSuffix);
if (null == userPrincipal)
{
    userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext)
    {
        SamAccountName = user.UserId,
        DisplayName = user.FullName,
        GivenName = user.FirstName,
        Surname = user.LastName,
        EmailAddress = user.Email,
        UserPrincipalName = user.UserId + upnSuffix,
        PasswordNeverExpires = true
    };
    //create user
    userPrincipal.Save();
}
return userPrincipal;
```

Set password:  `userPrincipal.SetPassword(password);`

Comment: Can you define "without success"? What *is* happening?

Comment: It's all coming back with failures; the DirectoryEntry approaches have been most direct with `8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C090579, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v3839`

Comment: The error code `52e` [means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--1300-1699-): "The user name or password is incorrect." How are you creating the accounts and setting the password?

Comment: Yes, I know - that's the trouble.  I can't get it to authenticate.  Since I'm running this in a test, I have the password that was just used, and I can see the entry through an LDAP browser.  I'm trying to understand the correct arguments/classes/methods to turn around and authenticate the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make extra sure that your authentication code is not the problem (I suspect it's not), you can try authenticating directly in Windows - either log into Windows with that account, or use [`runas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771525(v%3Dws.11)) at the command line:

```
runas /user:DOMAIN\username cmd
```

I suspect you'll have the same problem, which would mean there is an issue with the way the account is being created. I haven't created accounts with `UserPrincipal` (I have with `DirectoryEntry`), but I noticed a difference between what you're doing (creating the account and *then* setting the password) and other examples online. You can try either:

1. Move `userPrincipal.SetPassword(password)` to before `userPrincipal.Save()`, or
2. Use the [constructor that accepts the password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_UserPrincipal__ctor_System_DirectoryServices_AccountManagement_PrincipalContext_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_) so that it sets the password while creating the account:

```
userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext, user.UserId, password, true)
{
    DisplayName = user.FullName,
    GivenName = user.FirstName,
    Surname = user.LastName,
    EmailAddress = user.Email,
    UserPrincipalName = user.UserId + upnSuffix,
    PasswordNeverExpires = true
};
//create user
userPrincipal.Save();
```

See if that makes any difference.

Comment: Ok, this isn't the answer, but lead me to it.  I'm pretty sure that `SetPassword()` does not require a `Save()` afterwards. _However_, the actual problem was my user creation did not set the account to `Enabled` and the error messages were being intentionally vague.

Comment: Interesting. That did cross my mind, since if you create an account without a password, I know that it is automatically disabled and you have to specifically enable it. But I didn't think that was the case because of the error message. I would have expected to see error code `533`, which is supposed to mean that the account is disabled. Good to know!